# Fullscreen slideshow with vertical carousel.Fading in of fullscreen image issue

Tags: slider, slideshow, fullscreen, carousel, transition

I made a vertical carousel which consists of images that when clicked should be visible fullscreen. But the problem is i'm not able to figure out how to make sure the fullscreen images are preloaded or something and works like the thumbnail images(getting preloaded).

I'm not sure what approach to follow for preloading the fullscreen images using css background and how to make sure the images fadeIn or just some transition when i click on the thumbnail in the carousel.

Please have a look at the following link where my code is uploaded.
http://www.lluvia.me/slideshow/carousel.html

If its convenient,feel free to check the script by checking the source.
Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found this post and figured it might help you, [Preloading images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

Try and post some of the code in your body for future reference. :)

Quick and easy:

```
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        // Alternatively you could use:
        // (new Image()).src = this;
    });
}

// Usage:

preload([
    'img/imageName.jpg',
    'img/anotherOne.jpg',
    'img/blahblahblah.jpg'
]);
```

Or, if you want a jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.preload = function() {
this.each(function(){
    $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
});
}

// Usage:

$(['img1.jpg','img2.jpg','img3.jpg']).preload();
```

Alternatively, if you want to stick purely with CSS check out this page: http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/ You can just have the background image be positioned off screen then come on screen when needed.

```
#preload-01 { background: url(http://domain.tld/image-01.png) no-repeat -9999px -9999px; }
#preload-02 { background: url(http://domain.tld/image-02.png) no-repeat -9999px -9999px; }
#preload-03 { background: url(http://domain.tld/image-03.png) no-repeat -9999px -9999px; }
```